# Apache 2.4 webdav uploads without slash in filename

Tags: ubuntu, webdav, apache-2.4

I have webdav running on apache 2.4.2 on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS

virtual host config:

```
ServerAdmin test@test.com
ServerName test.com
ServerAlias www.test.com

ErrorLog "/usr/websites/logs/www.test.com-error_log"
CustomLog "/usr/websites/logs/www.test.com-access_log" common

DavLockDB "/usr/websites/var/DavLockWWW"

DocumentRoot "/usr/websites/www"
<Directory "/usr/websites/www">
    Options FollowSymlinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

Alias /davwww/ "/usr/websites/www"
<Location /davwww/>
    DAV On

    AuthType Digest
    AuthName "davwww"
    AuthUserFile "/usr/websites/www.digest.passwd"
    AuthDigestProvider file

    Require valid-user
</Location>
```

I can login and view the directory listing; however, when I create a file, it gets uploaded on the server without the folder separation character- slash.

/usr/websites directory:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  0 Jul 16 08:00 wwwNew Bitmap Image.bmp
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data   22 Jul 16 08:13 wwwNew Compressed (zipped) Folder.zip
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data    0 Jul 16 08:12 wwwNew IrfanView PSD File.psd
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data    0 Jul 16 08:04 wwwNew Microsoft Office Word Document.docx
```

apache access log:

```
[16/Jul/2012:08:13:37 +0400] "PUT /davwww/New%20Compressed%20(zipped)%20Folder.zip HTTP/1.1" 201 71
[16/Jul/2012:08:14:31 +0400] "PUT /davwww/New%20IrfanView%20PSD%20File.psd.zip HTTP/1.1" 201 71
```

The /usr/websites and all children folders have www-data and www-data user and group permissions with 777 permission (for sake of troubleshooting)

I used both WebDrive and BitKinex to test and samething happens.

Has anyone encountered this problem?

Comment: I created another server running ubuntu 10.04 and installed apache using apt-get install apache2 and had no problems with webdav.  Is anyone having trouble with webdav on apache 2.4?

Comment: solved it:
<Directory "/usr/websites/www"> needs to be <Directory "/usr/websites/www/">  *with ending slash.