# Apache 2.4 and WebDAV on Ubuntu 14.04, files uploading without slash

Tags: apache-2.4, webdav

This issue is similar to [Apache 2.4 webdav uploads without slash in filename](https://serverfault.com/questions/408015/apache-2-4-webdav-uploads-without-slash-in-filename?rq=1), but the solution specified there has not worked for me.

Basically, I have enabled mod_dav and mod_davfs, but the configuration does not appear to be letting me upload files properly. When I upload files, they are placed in the configured directory's parent directory, with a filename of "uploaddirfilename". I've been searching all over and can't figure out what the issue is with the configuration. This has been an issue on two Ubuntu servers using Apache 2.4, but hadn't previously been an issue with Debian and Apache 2.2.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName webdav.domain.com
    ServerAlias webdav.domain.com      
    ServerAdmin name@domain.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/sites/domain/htdocs"
    DavLockDB "/var/www/sites/domain/DavLock"
    <Directory "/var/www/sites/domain/htdocs/">
            Options Indexes FollowSymlinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
    Alias /htdocs/ "/var/www/sites/domain/htdocs"
    <Location /htdocs/>
            DAV On
            AuthType Digest
            AuthName "DAV"
            AuthDigestProvider file
            AuthUserFile "/var/www/sites/domain/.dav_pw_digest"
            Require valid-user
            ForceType text/plain
    </Location>
    Alias /logs /var/www/sites/domain/logs
</VirtualHost>
```

I've tried removing the Options there, no change. I've tried adding and removing slashes throughout the config, as the previous question mentioned adding one to his Directory section fixed his issue. It has not fixed mine, and adding a slash to the end of the "/var/www/sites/domain/htdocs" in the Alias line prevents me from logging in outright. I've also tried removing the Location section and the htdocs alias and moving the configuration within it to the Directory section, but this seems to break the config outright.

Authentication works, the DavLockDB is being written to, and files are being uploaded, they're just not being uploaded properly. Suggestions?

Comment: Isn't there an interoperability problem with your WebDAV client? Which one are you using?

Comment: I've tested using Cyberduck as well as the built-in functionality in MacOS/Finder. Both have the same problem, and neither had the problem with the Debian/Apache2.2 server.

Comment: A new wrinkle I noticed while testing this: subdirectories don't list, either. Using Finder, I get a blank directory. Using Cyberduck, I get `PROPFIND /subdirectory/ HTTP/1.1
Depth: 1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 99
Host: webdav.domain.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Cyberduck/4.4.5 (Mac OS X/10.7.5) (x86_64)
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Thu, 06 Nov 2014 02:36:48 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Content-Length: 299
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1`

Comment: The issue persists after upgrading to Ubuntu 14.10, so it's not specific to the version of Apache that comes with 14.04. That leads me to believe it's a config file issue but I am stumped as to specifically what.